# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function with Owl carousel

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

**I have a problem where I can fix this following the issue in the console on my WordPress website. Can anyone help me? I think there is a problem with the owl-carousel initialization or in the JQuery or something.**

Any help is much appreciated. Just to let you know I'm not a JS Developer :( Thanks, guys.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxal5.png)

```
$(document).ready((function() {
    $(".bullet_title-wrapper").on("click", (function() {
        $(this).siblings().slideToggle("slow"),
        +$(this).siblings().css("height")[0] ? $(this).children(".bullet_image").css({
            transform: "rotate(0deg)"
        }) : $(this).children(".bullet_image").css({
            transform: "rotate(90deg)"
        })
    }
    )),
    $(window).on("load resize", (function() {
        $(this).width() > 1440 ? $(".companies_images-wrapper.owl-carousel").trigger("destroy.owl.carousel") : $(".companies_images-wrapper.owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            loop: !0,
            nav: !0,
            dots: !1,
            mouseDrag: !1,
            touchDrag: !1,
            navText: ["<div class='companies_slider  left'></div>", "<div class='companies_slider  right'></div>"],
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 2
                },
                660: {
                    items: 3
                },
                768: {
                    items: 4
                },
                1200: {
                    items: 5
                }
            }
        })
    }
    ))
}
)),
$(document).ready((function() {
    const e = $(".companies_images-wrapper .companies_image").width();
    $(".companies_images-wrapper .companies_image:last-child").prependTo(".companies_images-wrapper");
    $(".companies_slider.left").on("click", s=>{
        $(".companies_images-wrapper").animate({
            left: +e
        }, 200, (function() {
            $(".companies_images-wrapper .companies_image:last-child").prependTo(".companies_images-wrapper"),
            $(".companies_images-wrapper").css("left", "")
        }
        ))
    }
    ),
    $(".companies_slider.right").on("click", s=>{
        $(".companies_images-wrapper").animate({
            left: -e
        }, 200, (function() {
            $(".companies_images-wrapper .companies_image:first-child").appendTo(".companies_images-wrapper"),
            $(".companies_images-wrapper").css("left", "")
        }
        ))
    }
    ),
    $(".nightmare-info .title-wrapper").on("click", (function() {
        $(this).siblings().slideToggle("slow"),
        +$(this).siblings().css("height")[0] ? $(this).children(".nightmare-info_icon").css({
            transform: "rotate(0deg)"
        }) : $(this).children(".nightmare-info_icon").css({
            transform: "rotate(90deg)"
        })
    }
    )),
    $(".companies_images-wrapper_carousel.owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        loop: !0,
        margin: 30,
        nav: !0,
        lazyLoad: !0,
        mouseDrag: !1,
        touchDrag: !1,
        navText: ["<div class='companies_slider left'></div>", "<div class='companies_slider right'></div>"],
        dots: !1,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 2,
                margin: 0
            },
            500: {
                items: 3
            },
            700: {
                items: 4
            },
            1e3: {
                items: 5
            },
            1300: {
                items: 6,
                margin: 40
            }
        }
    }),
    $(".companies_images-wrapper_carousel .owl-stage").css({
        display: "flex",
        "align-items": "center"
    }),
    $(".service-wrapper-responsive.owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        loop: !0,
        margin: 35,
        nav: !0,
        lazyLoad: !0,
        mouseDrag: !1,
        touchDrag: !1,
        navText: ["<div class='services_slider left'></div>", "<div class='services_slider right'></div>"],
        dots: !1,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            425: {
                items: 2
            },
            660: {
                items: 3
            }
        }
    }),
    //zr23 autoplay
    $(".slider-wrapper.owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        autoplay: 1,
        loop: 1,
        nav: !0,
        lazyLoad: !0,
        mouseDrag: !1,
        touchDrag: !1,
        navText: ["<div class='main_slider left'></div>", "<div class='main_slider right'></div>"],
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            }
        }
    }),
    $(".slider-mobile.owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        loop: !0,
        nav: !0,
        lazyLoad: !0,
        dotsEach: !0,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            }
        }
    });
    $(".owl-carousel").on("changed.owl.carousel", (function() {
        const e = $(".slider .owl-dots .owl-dot:nth-child(2)").hasClass("active");
        $(".slider-mobile .owl-dots .owl-dot:nth-child(2)").hasClass("active") ? $(".slider-mobile .owl-dot:nth-child(2) span").css({
            "background-color": "#0014C2"
        }) : $(".slider-mobile .owl-dot:nth-child(2) span").css({
            "background-color": "#D6D6D6"
        }),
        e ? ($(".slider .owl-dot:nth-child(2) span").css({
            "background-color": "#0014C2"
        }),
        $(".main_slider.right").removeClass("arrow-white").addClass("arrow-blue"),
        $(".main_slider.left").removeClass("arrow-white").addClass("arrow-blue")) : ($(".slider .owl-dot:nth-child(2)  span").css({
            "background-color": "rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"
        }),
        $(".main_slider.right").removeClass("arrow-blue").addClass("arrow-white"),
        $(".main_slider.left").removeClass("arrow-blue").addClass("arrow-white"))
    }
    ))
}
)),
$(document).ready((function() {
    $(".service-slogan_btns").on("click", "a", (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var s = $(this).attr("href")
          , a = $(s).offset().top;
        $("body,html").animate({
            scrollTop: a
        }, 1e3)
    }
    )),
    $(".service-slider.owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        loop: !0,
        nav: !0,
        mouseDrag: !1,
        touchDrag: !1,
        navText: ["<div class='service_slider left'></div>", "<div class='service_slider right'></div>"],
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            768: {
                items: 2
            }
        }
    })
}
));
const playBtn = document.querySelector(".shipping-app_video .play")
  , playText = document.querySelector(".shipping-app_video .text")
  , player = document.querySelector(".show-player")
  , modal = document.getElementById("myModal")
  , btn = document.getElementById("myBtn")
  , span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]
  , handledPlay = e=>{
    e.currentTarget && (player.style.display = "block",
    modal.style.display = "block",
    $("body").addClass("stop-scrolling"),
    player.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].play())
}
;
span && (span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none",
    $("body").removeClass("stop-scrolling"),
    player.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].pause()
}
),
window.onclick = function(e) {
    e.target === modal && (modal.style.display = "none",
    player.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].pause())
}

//,


if( $('body').is('.app') ){
    playBtn.addEventListener("click", handledPlay)
    playText.addEventListener("click", handledPlay)
}

//playBtn.addEventListener("click", handledPlay),
//playText.addEventListener("click", handledPlay),




$(document).ready((function() {
    $(window).on("load resize", (function() {
        $(this).width() > 1600 ? $(".features_bullets.owl-carousel").trigger("destroy.owl.carousel") : $(".features_bullets.owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            loop: !0,
            nav: !0,
            dots: !1,
            mouseDrag: !1,
            touchDrag: !1,
            navText: ["<div class='shipping-app_slider left'></div>", "<div class='shipping-app_slider right'></div>"],
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1
                },
                660: {
                    items: 2
                },
                1024: {
                    items: 3
                }
            }
        })
    }
    ))
}
)),
document.querySelector(".footer_form .submit-wrapper input").value = "Get started";




$(document).ready((function() {
    $('.wpcf7-phonetext').val('');
}
));
```